# How can you track missile damage in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building an RPG map for Minecraft and I have a system for rewarding individual XP by tracking the stats of mobs killed.I would also like to award shared XP (via scoreboard) for group kills ,i.e. several players defeating a single target, but currently only melee damage is tracked by the statistic "Damage dealt" so archers and spell casters will not receive credit for dealing ranged damage. Any ideas would be welcome.